# Laravel 8 Query builder update does not seem to work

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have this query that I'm trying to execute to update multiple rows in my database(Postgres). It seems to have worked at first since there was no error but the records that I'm trying to update were not affected.

This is the query:

```
DB::table('trea.close_account_track')
            ->where('year', $fin_year)
            ->where('month', $month)
            ->whereIn('trea_code', $trea_code)
            ->where('status', 'Y')
            ->update(['ag_download_status' => 'Y']);
```

And here's the generated SQL:

```
array (
    'query' => 'update "trea"."close_account_track" set "ag_download_status" = ? where "year" = ? and "month" = ? and "trea_code" in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and "status" = ?',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Y',
      1 => '2022',
      2 => '1',
      3 => '02',
      4 => '03',
      5 => '10',
      6 => '11',
      7 => '20',
      8 => '30',
      9 => '31',
      10 => '32',
      11 => '40',
      12 => '41',
      13 => '50',
      14 => '60',
      15 => '70',
      16 => '71',
      17 => '72',
      18 => '80',
      19 => 'Y',
    ),
    'time' => 2.47,
  )
```

If I run the generated SQL manually, the records were changed as expected. I have checked the error logs for both PHP and Postgres but there was also nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the query builder removes any zeroes from the variable even when it is a string or character hance the mismatch in the where query and therefore not updating appropriately. Case in point, the 3rd element(index 2) is supposed to be 01 but it changed to 1.